# Type declarations for function calling lodash `mapKeys`

Tags: typescript, lodash

I need a function mapping **camelCase** object keys to **snakeCase**. I want to use it multiple times with different objects.

I wrote function `mapKeysToSnakeCase` that works well, but I wonder if there is possible to use generic types instead of `any` to improve the definition.

*Any advice how it can be done?*

```
export function mapKeysToSnakeCase(data: any): any {
    return mapKeys(data, (value, key) => snakeCase(key));
}
```

Before:

```
const camelCase = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
};
```

After:

```
const snakeCase = {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Smith',
};
```

---

**@edit**

I tried previously with new type definition (like first answer suggested), but I end up with warning in usage context and it is why I want to use some generic types for it.

```
sync getData(): Promise<X> {
    (...)
    return mapKeysToSnakeCase(camelCaseX);
}
```

error:

```
TS2741: Property 'first_name' is missing in type 'KV' but required in type 'X'.
```

Comment: Why not using `snakecase-keys` lib? Using `npm install snakecase-keys @types/snakecase-keys` to install it, I could convert your sample KV as you wanted.

Comment: Currently not possible. Here's relevant suggestion https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754

Comment: I posted solution proposed by my team mate. It suits my needs well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask my team mate to help me with this and he prepared best suited solution:

```
export function mapKeysToSnakeCase<R>(data: Record<string, any>): R {
    return mapKeys(data, (value, key) => snakeCase(key)) as R;
}
```

well fit with context like:

```
sync getData(): Promise<X> {
    (...)
    return mapKeysToSnakeCase<X>(camelCaseX);
}
```

Comment: so you're basically adding types for transformation manually..

Comment: IMO it looks much better then `fun(data: any): any` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define key-value type as follows:

```
type KV = { [x: string]: string }; // x is an key of type string and value have string type too
```

and use it:

```
export function mapKeysToSnakeCase(data: KV): KV {
  return mapKeys(data, (value, key) => snakeCase(key));
}
```

Comment: yep, indeed, but in this case return type is specified as KV, while I want it to be more generic, example: 
`async getData(): Promise<X> { (...) return mapKeysToSnakeCase(camelCaseX); }`
error: `TS2741: Property 'first_name' is missing in type 'KV' but required in type 'X'.`